# How to unserialize a serialized array sent to the server using GET method with a jQuery Ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an array from an URL I've sent from a JQuery Ajax call to a PHP script in the server.

### What I have done

I've been sending variables with values to the server successfully with jQuery Ajax this way:

```
// A simple text from an HTML element:
var price = $("#price option:selected").val();
// Yet another simple text:
var term1 = $('#term1').val();
```

Then I prepare the data to be sent via Ajax this way:

```
var data = 'price=' + price + '&term1=' + term1;
//if I alert it, I get this: price=priceString&term1=termString
```

And send it with jQuery Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "script.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType:'html',
        success: function (html) {
            // Do something successful
        }
});
```

Then I get it in the server this way:

```
$price = (isset($_GET['price'])) ? $_GET['price'] : null;
$term1 = (isset($_GET['term1'])) ? $_GET['term1'] : null;
```

And I'm able to use my variables easily as I need. However, I need to do this with an array.

### Main question

Reading a lot, I've managed to learn the professional way to send an array to the server: serialize it! I've learnt this way to do it with jQuery:

```
var array_selected = [];
// This is used to get all options in a listbox, no problems here:
$('#SelectIt option:not(:selected), #SelectIt option:selected').each(function() {
   array_selected.push({ name: $(this).val(), value: $(this).html().substring($(this).html().indexOf(' '))});
});
var array_serialized = jQuery.param(array_selected);
// If I alert this I get my array serialized successfully with in the form of number=string:
//Ex. 123=stringOne&321=StringTwo
```

This seems to be right. I add this to the data as before:

```
var data = 'price=' + price + '&' + array_selected + '&term1=' + term1;
//if I alert it, I get this: price=priceString&term1=termString&123=stringOne&321=StringTwo
```

How do I reconstruct (unserialize) my array in the server? I've tried the same as before:

```
$array_serialized = (isset($_GET['array_serialized'])) ? $_GET['array_serialized'] : null;
```

with no success! Any ideas why? How can I get my serialized array passed this way in the server as another array which PHP can handle so I can use it?

Or am I complicating my life myself needlessly? All I want is to send an array to the server.

Comment: Well I don't have any clue what JSON is,I just know it's Javascript server side... I really should learn it I know, but also I'm not able to install anything in the servers =/ they've got old technology and they won't install/update anything u.u But thanks =)

Comment: JSON is useful if you want to send an array from javascript to PHP or the other way round. In PHP there is `json_decode` and `json_encode` which allows you to turn a javascript array into a PHP array and the other way round.

Comment: @hakre Thanks a lot for your idea, but I really needed to do it as described, but I'll surely try your way next time in the future. For now, my problem it's solved. THANKS AGAIN =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name a variable with `[]` in the end of it, it will create an array out of the values passed with that name.

For example, `http://www.example.com/?data[]=hello&data[]=world&data[]=test`, will result in the array `$_GET["data"] == array('hello', 'world', 'test');` created in PHP.

In the same way, you can create an associative array in PHP: `http://www.example.com/?data[first]=foo&data[second]=bar` will result in `$_GET["data"] == array("first" => "foo", "second" => "bar");`

BTW, you might be interested in using jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), if those fit your client side serializing needs.

Comment: Mmm... I can't fully understand... How can I accomplish this answer you gave me? I'm just passing an array to JQuery.param() function and it serializes it just with the contents of the array, with no reference to the array name (ex data[]) Any ideas how to accomplish this? u.u THANKS

Comment: `jQuery.param()` serializes it with the `name` property as the variable name, and the `value` as the value. You should have the `name` as I described - `data[]` or `data[price]`, whatever fits your needs, and then use it. In your example, I would change the `array_selected.push` name part from `name: $(this).val()` to `name: 'data[' + $(this).val() + ']'`.

Comment: Uffff... I had to study a lot to fully understand your answer. Maybe I was just unaware of some concepts. THANKS A LOT =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too knowledgeable with PHP, but I think you may have overlooked something pretty simple, [`<?--php unserialize($string) ?>`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: I did read about it before, but for the needs of my application I needed to do it as described, but thanks a lot for your help =)